# Remove a part of a string

Tags: r, subset

I got a string;

```
"Enviroment is dangerous.123"
```

Now I want to remove everything after "dangerous" so the result will be

```
"Enviroment is dangerous"
```

I got different text strings of different length. So it needs to respond to the string "dangerous"

How do I do that?

Comment: Also `sub("(^.*dangerous).*$", "\\1", "Enviroment is dangerous.123")`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match the `.` followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`) until the end of the string (`$`) and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\.\\d+$", "", str1)
#[1] "Enviroment is dangerous"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "Enviroment is dangerous.123"
```